# Is it possible to make a bit map image as array?

Tags: objective-c

I would like to make a bit map image as follow array.
 I think that will need to use quartz...

How to can make a bit map image?

```
int bit_map[10][10] = {{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
                       {0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0},
                       {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                       {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                       {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
                       {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
                       {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
                       {0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0}};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code to create a CGImageRef (`cir`) from the `C` array. Note that things can be simpler if the `C` array is one dimensional with values of 0 and 255.

```
size_t   width        = 10;
size_t   height       = 10;
int bit_map[10][10] = {
    {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
    {0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
    {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
    {0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0}
};

UIImage *barCodeImage = nil;
size_t   bitsPerComponent = 8;
size_t   bitsPerPixel     = 8;
size_t   bytesPerRow      = (width * bitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;

void  *imageBytes;
size_t imageBytesSize = height * bytesPerRow;

imageBytes = calloc(1, imageBytesSize); 

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
        int pixel = bit_map[j][i];
        if (pixel == 1)
            pixel = 255;
            ((unsigned char*)imageBytes)[((i+1) * (j+1)) - 1] = pixel;
    }
}

CGDataProviderRef provider       = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, imageBytes, imageBytesSize, releasePixels);
CGColorSpaceRef   colorSpaceGrey = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGImageRef cir = CGImageCreate (width,
                                height,
                                bitsPerComponent,
                                bitsPerPixel,
                                imageBytesSize,
                                colorSpaceGrey,
                                kCGImageAlphaNone,
                                provider,
                                NULL,
                                NO,
                                kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceGrey);
```